# Holding Shift and Click solution

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I`m trying to make a simple macro shift and left click are hold for 20 sec and durring that time another key is in the loop for this 20 sec.

Seems like after shift and click are down nothing else i can make on working in ahk.

this is the example i made but its not working

```
$4::
 {
Send, {Shift Down}{LButton Down}
Send, {1 20}
sleep 20000 ;
Send, {LButton Up}{Shift Up}
 }
return
```